# Rotational Hamiltonian for Molecules

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, hamiltonian-formalism, rigid-body-dynamics, molecules

I would like to know where the classical rotational hamiltonian for rigid diatomic molecules comes from. In the reference I only find the expression

$$ H_{\rm rot}=\frac{1}{2I} \left[ p_\theta^2 + \frac{p_\varphi^2}{\sin^2\!\theta}  \right] $$

I understand that I have to separate in CM motion and rigid body rotation, but I not exactly how to do it with hamiltonian formalism

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, you need to separate the center-of-mass (COM) motion and the rotational motion.
To achieve this you can derive the Lagrangian in a straight-forward way,
and then do a Legendre transformation to get the Hamiltonian.

Because the question is tagged as homework-and exercises I will only
sketch an outline without the calculational details.

[image]
Consider a diatomic molecule. Let $\mathbf{R}$ be the COM position,
and $\mathbf{r}_1$ and $\mathbf{r}_2$ the positions of the two atomic nuclei relative to the COM.
Then the total kinetic energy is
$$T=\frac{1}{2}m_1(\dot{\mathbf{R}}+\dot{\mathbf{r}}_1)^2
   +\frac{1}{2}m_2(\dot{\mathbf{R}}+\dot{\mathbf{r}}_2)^2.$$

By expanding the squares and regrouping the terms you get
$$T=\frac{1}{2}(m_1+m_2)\dot{\mathbf{R}}^2
   +\frac{1}{2}(m_1\dot{\mathbf{r}}_1^2+m_2\dot{\mathbf{r}}_2^2)
   +\dot{\mathbf{R}}\underbrace{(m_1\dot{\mathbf{r}}_1+m_2\dot{\mathbf{r}}_2)}_{=\mathbf{0}}.$$

Here the last term is zero because the COM is defined by
$m_1\mathbf{r}_1+m_2\mathbf{r}_2=\mathbf{0}$.

Rewriting $\dot{\mathbf{r}}_1^2$ and $\dot{\mathbf{r}}_2^2$ in spherical coordinates
and using the abbreviations $M=m_1+m_2$ (the total mass) and
$I=m_1r_1^2+m_2r_2^2$ (the moment of inertia) you get the total Lagrangian
$$L=T=\frac{1}{2}M\dot{\mathbf{R}}^2+\frac{1}{2}I(\dot{\theta}^2+\dot{\varphi}^2\sin^2\theta)$$
where obviously the first term describes the COM motion
and the second term describes the rotational motion.

Finally, from this total Lagrangian you calculate the total Hamiltonian
(see [Hamiltonian mechanics - Calculating a Hamiltonian from a Lagrangian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics#Calculating_a_Hamiltonian_from_a_Lagrangian)) and get
$$H=\frac{1}{2M}\mathbf{P}^2+\frac{1}{2I}\left(p_\theta^2+\frac{p_\varphi^2}{\sin^2\theta}\right).$$
Here again the first term describes the COM motion and the second term describes the rotational motion.

Comment: How about a molecule which is not linear (i.e. not all lined up along a line), such as H$_2$O? I think something further is needed (so as to get 3 degrees of freedom in the equipartition theorem).

Comment: @AndrewSteane That is a much more difficult problem. It is handled e.g. in
[Rigid rotator - Arbitrarily shaped rigid rotator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_rotor#Arbitrarily_shaped_rigid_rotor)
using the 3 Euler angles as the coordinates.